# ion-toolbar in header make ion content not scrollable

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using ionic to build a web app.
My template is:

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="large-title-fix">
    <ion-title>MyLinkedin</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="type">
      <ion-segment-button value="Applicant" >
        <ion-label>Applicant</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="Offeror">
        <ion-label>Offeror</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="Company">
        <ion-label>Company</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
      <app-sign-up-applicant *ngIf="type==='Applicant'"></app-sign-up-applicant>

      <app-sign-up-offeror *ngIf="type==='Offeror'"></app-sign-up-offeror>

      <app-sign-up-company *ngIf="type==='Company'"></app-sign-up-company>
</ion-content>
```

but this make the ion content not entirely scrollable

Here's a gif to display what happen
[image]

It seems like it can scroll, but it doesn't show the entire content of the page

Edit: the problem, in some way, is the toolbar, in fact if I remove the toolbar, It works.
I can't understand why.

Comment: i think you need to set bottom padding or margin like 150px or 100px

Comment: I tried to add style="margin-bottom: 100px" to <ion-content> but it did't work. I also tried to set margin to 500px but nothing changed

Comment: not in style padding-bottom not working you can use `--padding-bottom` or `--margin-bottom` in .scss file